# Which implicit declarations are allowed / valid?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c11, c17, implicit-declaration

It is known that:

- implicit declaration of function is invalid
- implicit declaration of variable is invalid

Which implicit declarations are allowed / valid?

One example is identifier `__func__`. Are there other examples?

Comment: What is the implicit declaration?

Comment: Maybe `main` function?

Comment: `__func__` is the one and only context where the current standard mentions "implicit declaration" or "implicitly declared". There are no other implicitly declared things.

Comment: So you found this text about `__func__` in 6.4.2.2 predefined identifiers. What other predefined identifiers do you find in that chapter other than `__func__`? And that would be the answer to the question.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Can you provide an answer "There are no other implicitly declared things"?

Comment: @Lundin Out of curiosity: why both gcc and clang define `__func__` at file scope? msvc doesn't.

Comment: Does it? Hmm well that sounds curious. And it sounds like a potentially good new question if you can post your research regarding how you came to that conclusion.

Comment: @Lundin Both gcc and clang allow at file scope to assign `__func__` and apply `sizeof` to it while issuing a warning following by generation of an executable. While msvc issues an error. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/Gnh47efc7.

Comment: I guess the standard doesn't really mention what happens if used at file scope. Printing the pointer from your example just gives an empty string on gcc and clang. "...immediately following the opening brace of each function definition" kind of implies that `__func__` has no business outside a function definition though. Maybe you have found the first example in history where MSVC actually has better conformance than other compilers :)